Missing "Sync Destination" and "Switch to Workspace" Options in VS Code for Databricks
I am trying to connect Visual Studio Code to Databricks, but I am missing the "Sync Destination" and "Switch to Workspace" options. My current VS Code version is 1.96.2.
I have followed the setup instructions, but these options are not appearing. What could I be doing wrong?

Installed DB Extension
Configured DB CLI
Connected to my DB account


read documentations. Answer is lengthy. or if you like search for this youtube video
Databricks VS Code Extension v2: Setup and Feature Demo
